# Not able to read values from form React JS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, api, mongoose

The below code is written to get the value from the code and send it to the API, but values are undefined

```
class Register extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state= {
            Name: '',
            Email: '',
            Password:'',
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    onChange(e){
       
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }
    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()

        const user = {
            Name: this.state.name,
            Email: this.state.email,
            Password: this.state.password
        }
        console.log(this.state.value); // returns undefined
        register(user).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            if(res) {
                this.props.history.push('/login')
            }
        })
    }
```

the values fetched from the forms are undefined, how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. This means that the language keywords, variables, function names, and any other identifiers must always be typed with a consistent capitalization of letters.

In your state you have capitalized names:

```
        this.state= {
            Name: '',
            Email: '',
            Password:'',
        }
```

But inside `onSubmit` you use lowercased names:

```
        const user = {
            Name: this.state.name, // should be -> Name: this.state.Name
            Email: this.state.email, // same here
            Password: this.state.password // same here
        }
```

You need to be consistent and use same capitalization in both places. Usually in JS it is lowercased (or if more specific - camelCased) names for everything expect classes and constructor functions.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, but after this I am not able to type anything in input field

Comment: If you changed variables to lowercase then you probably forgot to change `name` property for input element. It should also be consistent with your naming because you use it inside `onChange` function -> `this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})`

Comment: I am new to react but  `this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})` is same as before, then why this problem is been arising?

Comment: No, I mean you need to change `name` prop for input component. It probably looks something like that in your code: `<input type="text" name="Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChange} />`. Change `name="Email"` to `name="email"`

Comment: this was very helpful, the issue has been resolved, Thanks!